# mysql Timediff() function returns 0.0000

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

In Sql Server:

```
declare @totalUsageInSeconds decimal(15,6)
SELECT @totalUsageInSeconds = @totalUsageInSeconds + DATEDIFF(SECOND, @resourceStartTime, @resourceEndTime)
```

The above query gives correct datedifference in seconds

But in Mysql , difference is seconds is given as 0.0000:(please refer below)

```
declare _totalUsageInSeconds decimal(15,6);
SELECT @totalUsageInSeconds = @totalUsageInSeconds + TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(_resourceStartTime, _resourceEndTime));
```

can i know the reason and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a variable it is set to `NULL`. When you add anything to `NULL` you get a `NULL`.

Change this line:

```
declare @totalUsageInSeconds decimal(15,6) = 0;
```

or add:

```
select @totalUsageInSeconds = 0
```